# Conjoint Analysis Simulation SPSS - excluded subjects

Tags: spss, conjoint-analysis

With SPSS when I run a simulation with conjoint analysis I got this message:

"142 out of 155 subjects are used in the Bradley-Terry-Luce and Logit methods because these subjects have all nonnegative scores".

I think SPSS excluded those respondents because their simulated score was negative for some profiles.

Each excluded respondent displays this message:
"Negative simulation scores or all zero simulation scores are found. This subject will not be included in computing preference probabilities using the Bradley-Terry-Luce or Logit methods"

Is there a way to include the excluded subject?
Is it possible to avoid this issue with other softwares?

Thank you very much,

Fabio Spinnato

Comment: I'm afraid this is off-topic for this site because the question is solely about how to get this or that software to accomplish a certain task.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this should be considered off-topic. Certainly asking for SPSS code is off-topic (& on the surface, that's what this Q is). But I doubt this is particular to SPSS or that there is some function call type solution. I suspect the OP needs to understand the nature of their data & BTL models more fully, which would mean it should stay here. However, I don't know enough about BTL models myself to be sure.